# Making a Map Behaves Like an ArrayList

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, hash, hashmap

This is something like a java puzzle I have read, I know there is no practical benefit. The question was-
"**Can you implement an `ArrayList` like structure using `Map`? And what would be the benefit of this construction?**"

Then I think we can use a construction like this (to store `String`) -

```
Map<Integer, String> dummyArrayList = new HashMap<>();
```

Now we can use the structure working as an `ArrayList`  like this -

```
dummyArryList.put(1, "firstString");
dummyArrayList.put(2, "secondString");
dummyArrayList.put(9, "9thString");
```

Here the keys are used like an index of `ArrayList`. I think the benefit of this structure (please correct me if I am wrong)-

1. Item can be added at any index where in `ArrayList` items are added at the last of the `ArrayList.`
2. Item can be accessed faster since hashing is used ( a bit confused about this)

I know we should not use these type of structure in real life. But I just want to know whether the hashing can be used faster than indexing to access an item from a collection?

Comment: No, it will never really be faster.

Comment: @LouisWasserman An extremely sparse list (think one with two non-null values, one at 0 and one at Integer.MAX_VALUE) would definitely be faster to create, and probably faster to operate on -- assumining you could even create the ArrayList without running out of memory, which you very well may not be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agreed with the first point it can be treated as a feature.

But about accessing it will be slower that `ArrayList` i guess.

As in this case it will go like

- calculate the hash  of key (`hashcode()`)
- match the hash value
- match the key again ( `equals()`)
- access item

Where `ArrayList` will work like

- find the block with response to the first (0 index) as like array
- access the item

Answer (score 1):

One benefit is the ability to have "sparse" values without a memory hit. With an ArrayList if you have an item at position 0 and 1,001, it leaves 1,000 empty spaces and takes up a lot of extra memory. With a HashMap, there is no hit. A similar effect happens with extending the maximum entry in a sparse list (if not initialized appropriately). With an ArrayList the entire contents would have to be copied into a new ArrayList of the new size. In general, the HashMap's size will be related to the number of entries, the ArrayList will be sized based off the highest position.

You could also map negative numbers, something that isn't doable with an ArrayList (this could be good or bad depending on the situation).

Another potential benefit would have the ability to have null values "explicit" vs unmapped. With an ArrayList two states would be null and having a value. With a HashMap, you would have a 3rd state of being unmapped which would technically be different from null. This "feature" could be used or ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know In array I can leave some indexed position empty. That means I can put some value at index 1 and index 5 of a array[20] and can leave rest of them empty. But is it possible for a `ArrayList` ?.

Comment: Yes, ArrayList.set(int, Object) does that.